# cannot load such file -- restclient/instrumentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rest-client

While adding instrumentation tracing to my existing app, I got the error `cannot load such file -- restclient/instrumentation`

Here's the bulk of the stack dump:

```
% bundle exec rails console 
cannot load such file -- restclient/instrumentation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  60: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
  59: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  58: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  57: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
  56: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
     ...snip...
  12: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:61:in `query'
  11: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:571:in `log'
  10: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/ar-octopus-0.10.2/lib/octopus/abstract_adapter.rb:13:in `instrument'
   9: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
   8: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:580:in `block in log'
   7: from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
     ...snip...
   2: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
   1: from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in query'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:20:in `result_as_array': undefined method `nfields' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the restclient-instrumentation gem to Gemfile:

```
gem 'restclient-instrumentation'
```

...and then run `bundle install`, as described in https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/ruby-restclient-instrumentation#installation